# Error in inputting a 2d character array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I am entering a 2D character array and have to stop entering when the user hit the enter key . But my code is not showing any output.
Input:

```
5  // where this is the number of columns, 
   // number of rows are unknown so have taken maximum rows as: 40
```

array:

```
toioynnkpheleaigshareconhtomesnlewx
```

Expected output:

```
i = 7, j = 5
```

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
    char a[100][100];
    int n, i, j, p, q;
    cin >> n;
    if(n==0)
       exit(0);

    for(i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            cin >> a[i][j];

            if(a[i][j]==13)  // 13 = ASCII code for enter key
                goto jump;
        }
    }

jump:
    cout<<i<<"\n"<<j<<"\n";

}
```

But it is not printing anything.

What could be wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `cin` ignores white space and newline ('\n', whose ASCII code is 13). This means the condition `if(a[i][j] == 13)` never evaluates to true.

Solution: Use `cin.get(a[i][j])` instead of `cin>>a[i][j]`

This works because the `cin.get()` method does not ignore the newline character ('\n').

Comment: Try changing the if condition to: `if(a[i][j] == '\n')` instead of comparing the value with 13.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: It works; check this link out: https://ideone.com/OegC7h Be sure to press the enter key after the string. The output is 7 0 because j has come back to 0 when the code takes in the newline character. j can never be 5 because the for loop wouldn't execute in that case, as the condition is: `j<n` and not `j<=n`